# ImageList shows only one image

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to fill a listview with a database, with each row displaying an image  retrieved from a path. It works and an image is displayed in the row, but the problem is that the same image shows up for every list item. So it uses the image from the first database entry for all of the entries. 
Here is the code retrieving and displaying the images:

```
DataTable tab = myConn.GetSchema("Tables");
foreach (DataRow row in tab.Rows) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
}
string mySelectQuery = "Select * from staff";
OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(mySelectQuery, myConn);
OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
ImageList imgList = new ImageList();
while (reader.Read()) {
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(reader.GetString(0), 0);
    item.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString(1));
    item.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString(2));
    // gets image from path in db
    imgList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(reader.GetString(3)));
    listView1.SmallImageList = imgList;
    item.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString(4));
    item.ImageIndex = 0;
    listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're sharing the same imageList object among all of them. You create it before entering the loop, and then on each iteration, you add another image to the end, but you always tell each new listview item to use the first image in the list. Since it's the same list object every time, that's the same first image every time.

You could just create a new image list for each item:

```
        while (reader.Read()) {
            //  Create a new one each time.
            ImageList imgList = new ImageList();

            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(reader.GetString(0), 0);
```